Sonarqube and Jenkins Connectivity Issue
My Jenkins and Sonarqube are on my local machine. I can access and log in both using the port 8080 and 9000 consecutively.
If I run mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 on my cli, it works fine.
Then using same in Jenkinsfile, it throws error saying

Cannot locate Sonar Server on  http://localhost:9000"

Please note I have sonarscanner installed on Jenkins and sonar token was copied to Jenkins too.
What could be wrong?

Try to use Your Machine's IP Address
Replace localhost with the IP address of your local machine in the SonarQube URL.
Find your local machine's IP address:
I don't know if you are using windows or linux but try with Ipconfig
Update the SonarQube host URL in your Jenkinsfile:
mvn sonar:sonar \
    -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN \
    -Dsonar.host.url=http://<your-local-ip>:9000
Restart Jenkins (optional) and test again.

Then restart Jenkins
